# Getter not working if the setter is internal

Tags: c#, wcf, class

I have a class with this property

`public bool IsDeleted { get; internal set; }`

I'm using this class over some WCF services, playing with some instances of the class. All the other public properties are visible after getting an instance of the class, except IsDeleted. If I make the setter public, IsDeleted works too.

Any ideea of this weird behaviour?

Comment: A property that is serialized by a WCF service must always implement a public getter and public setter.

Comment: It also doesn't really matter what kind of functionality you put in there, because you'll lose it anyway on the client side. Perhaps you want to use the WCF service as both a service and a class library, in that case you can only restrict it to an empty setter and add an internal method that sets the backing field.

Comment: @Silvermind True, a property always does need a public getter and setter, so serialize a private member instead :) (see my answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most all serialization methods in .NET (including WCF) require a accessible getter and setter to work because it must be able to set the property to a value when it desearalizes the incoming field.

There is a work around, you can mark the backing store private member as the serialization field instead.

```
[DataContract]
class Foo
{
    [DataMember(Name="IsDeleted")]
    private bool _isDeleted;

    public bool IsDeleted 
    { 
       get { return _isDeleted; }
       internal set { _isDeleted = value; } 
    }
}
```

However, if your client does not have a refrence to `Foo` as a refrence DLL it will create a auto-generated proxy that will will look like.

```
class Foo
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

To prevent that from happening make sure metadata publishing is turned off and you distribute a DLL with `Foo` to all clients who will consume your WCF service.

---

If you don't want to pass around a DLL you can use the workaround [Silvermind mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936634/getter-not-working-if-the-setter-is-internal#comment29669430_19936634) by having the setter do nothing and having a internal method to set the backing member.

```
[DataContract]
class Foo
{
    private bool _isDeleted;

    public bool IsDeleted 
    { 
       get { return _isDeleted; }
       set {  } 
    }

    internal void SetIsDeletedInternal(bool value)
    {
        _isDeleted = value;
    }
}
```

However note that if you do this and the client passes a `Foo` object to you this will always force set `_isDeleted` to `default(bool)` on the object you receive from the client.

Comment: That's a nice workaround, I like the first approach, but I would only use it if someone commands me to.

Comment: @Silvermind I agree, the order I would handle this would be 1) Use a separate DTO object that has a public getter and setter. 2) Deal with a public setter in my code. 3) This workaround. 4) Your workaround. 5) Make the IsDeleted check a function instead of a property.

Comment: I agree. A little more effort for much better maintainability ;)

Comment: @gabitzish out of curiosity what solution of the 5 did you do?